# Power of group (order 6)

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Determine all powers to $x$, the result should be a group of
order 6. Is this group isomorphic with $S_3$?

$$x=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4  &5 \\2 
 &4  &5  &1  &3 
\end{pmatrix}$$

How do i start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to take a permutation to a power, you just iterate. So, to get $x^2$, remember that $x$ is $$ x=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &2  &3  &4  &5 \\ 2 & 4  &5  &1  &3 \end{pmatrix}$$ So if I apply that permutation twice, $1$ will get sent to $2$ the first time, and the second time that 2 will get sent to 4. So 1 gets sent to 4. Likewise, 2 gets sent first to 4 and then to 1, 3 gets sent to 5 and then back to 3, 4 gets sent 1 and then to 2, and 5 gets sent to 3 and back to 5. So $$ x^2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &2  &3  &4  &5 \\ 4 & 1  & 3  &2  &5 \end{pmatrix}$$ In the same way, if do the transformation again, 3 times, 1 will get sent to 2 and then to 4 and then ultimately back to 1. And so on, you can compute all of the powers of $x$. When you do it 6 times, you'll get back to the identity, so $x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5$ will form a group under composition with 6 elements.

To see why it's not isomorphic to $S_3$, as @Aryaman has noted, notice that $x^a \cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$. So $x^b \cdot x^a = x^{b + a} = x^{a + b} = x^a \cdot x^b$. So elements in this group always commute with each other, this group is *abelian.* The same is not true of $S_3$ (can you see why?), so this group cannot be isomorphic to $S_3$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: All elements in the (sub)group that you get will commute with each other. Is that the case in $S_3$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** We can write $x = (124)(35)$ in cycle notation. To find the powers of $x$, we can use the fact that disjoint cycles commute.

Now, a group $G$ is cyclic if and only if $G = \langle x \rangle$ for some $x \in G$, i.e. $G$ can be generated by only one element. Is $S_3$ a cyclic group?